# Setting a Navbar dropdown button active (Change color) once a link inside the button is also active

Tags: html, css

So I have been trying to set a Navbar dropdown button active (Change color) once a link inside the button is also active, cant seem to work out how, new to html

I have set up the navbar on the top of the page with some links inside aswell as a few drop buttons. i have posted a sample of the HTML code along with the CSS.

```css
.navbar a.active {
  color: red;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #325d81;
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 21px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar a:hover:not(.active),
.dropdown-content a:hover:not(.active),
.dropbtn {
  color: #B0B0B0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  background-color: ;
  min-width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  float: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4078a5;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover:not(.active) {
  color: #B0B0B0;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>`
      </ul>`
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a class="active" href="Stats.html">Stats</a>
        <a href="Images.html">Images</a>
        <a href="Document.html">Document</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

any help would be super. i have tried looking it up.

Answer (score 0):

This code is for Stats.html similarly change the class name to "active" in
other html files

```
<a class="active" href="Stats.html">Stats</a>
<a href="Images.html">Images</a>
<a href="Document.html">Document</a>
```

This is for Images.html

```
<a href="Stats.html">Stats</a>
<a class="active" href="Images.html">Images</a>
<a href="Document.html">Document</a>
```

And this is for Document.html

```
<a href="Stats.html">Stats</a>
<a href="Images.html">Images</a>
<a class="active" href="Document.html">Document</a>
```

If you do so, then clicking the button will take you to that page and also makes that button red.
You can use same css

Comment: This will change the color of the link in the drop down menu, not the actual drop down menu button

Answer (score 0):

The way is to create separate classes for each button. This code works fine.

```css
.navbar a.active {
  color: red;
}

.navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #325d81;
  padding: 0px;
}

.navbar a {
  float: left;
  font-size: 21px;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dropdown {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
  font-size: 21px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 30px;
  background-color: inherit;
  font-family: inherit;
  margin: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navbar a:hover:not(.active),
.dropdown-content a:hover:not(.active),
.dropbtn {
  color: #B0B0B0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  background-color: ;
  min-width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.inactive1 {
  float: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4078a5;
}

.inactive2 {
  float: none;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #4078a5;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover:not(.active) {
  color: #B0B0B0;
}
.active
{
  background-color: #325d81;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <button class="dropbtn" onclick="myFunction()">Dropdown
        <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
      </button>`
      </ul>`
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="myDropdown">
        <a class="active" href="Stats.html">Stats</a>
        <a class="inactive1" href="Images.html">Images</a>
        <a class="inactive2" href="Document.html">Document</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```